# Three javascript functions on one single page - disfunctional

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, slide

my first post here so let's do this. I have a single page website with three image sliders on each div. One Div after the other:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 3;
function slide(x) {
var Image = document.getElementById('img');
imagecount = imagecount + x;
if(imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1;}
if(imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
Image.src = "img/Slide1/img"+ imagecount +".jpg"; }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 3;
function slide(x) {
var Image = document.getElementById('img2');
imagecount = imagecount + x;
if(imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1;}
if(imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
Image.src = "img/Slide2/comd"+ imagecount +".jpg"; }
</script>
```

Because I have added another code too, the navigation buttons that are on the first don't work for the first DIV but the second one.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
```

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="img/slide1/img1.jpg" id="img">
    <div id="left_holder"> <img onclick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="img/Slide1/leftandright/leftred_up.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/leftred_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/leftred_up.png'"> </div>
    <div id="right_holder"> <img onclick="slide(1)" class="right" src="img/Slide1/leftandright/rightred_up.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/rightred_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/rightred_up.png'"> </div>
</div>
```

HTML for the second JS function:

```
<div id="main-content2">
```

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="img/slide2/comd1.jpg" id="img2">
    <div id="left_holder"> <img  onclick="slide2(-1)" class="left" src="img/Slide2/leftandright/leftorn_up.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Slide2/leftandright/leftorn_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Slide2/leftandright/leftorn_up.png'"> </div>
    <div id="right_holder"> <img onclick="slide2(1)" class="right" src="img/Slide2/leftandright/rightorn_up.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Slide2/leftandright/rightorn_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Slide2/leftandright/rightorn_up.png'"> </div>
</div>
```

I'll be replying rapidly to the responses so if you have to ask anything go ahead!

Be gentle please

Comment: You called the function `slide2` in your second HTML example, but both functions are still called `slide`. Ideally, you would pass the parameters needed to differentiate the effects into a single function. You're currently redefining and clobbering variables in your current JS.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Thanks for the reply mate. I think the slide2 is the image source and it's the name of the folder.

Comment: Just because you have the codes in seperate script tags doesn't mean they won't conflict. Naming a variable such as `var imagecount= 1` like that would make it accessible to the global scope. You should create a wrapper for this and then continue.

Comment: @EasyBB I'm new to coding so by adding a wrapper that would do what exactly? Instead of ID use wrapper?

Comment: No no, a wrapper is a function basically. I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: you need to adapt your code so you only need one slide function with added parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function slideShow(element,count) {
    var imagecount = parseInt( element.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current"), 10);
    var total = parseInt( element.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-count"), 10);
        var Image = element.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img");
        imagecount = imagecount + count;
        element.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",imagecount);
        if(imagecount > total){ 
           imagecount = 1;
           element.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",imagecount);
        }else if(imagecount < 1){ 
           imagecount = total;
           element.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",imagecount);
        }

        Image.src = "img/Slide1/img"+ imagecount +".jpg"; 
}
```

Now your html

```
<div id="slide_show_1" data-count="3" data-current="1">
    <img src="img/slide1/img1.jpg" id="img">
    <div id="left_holder"> 
        <img onclick="new slideShow(this,1)" class="left" src="img/Slide1/leftandright/leftred_up.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/leftred_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/leftred_up.png'"> 
    </div>
    <div id="right_holder"> 
        <img onclick="new slideShow(this,1)" class="right" src="img/Slide1/leftandright/rightred_up.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/rightred_over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Slide1/leftandright/rightred_up.png'"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO** http://jsbin.com/bejozuquqo/1/edit

Comment: EasyBB, my problem has fixed but I will take the knowledge you have provided me and use it in the future. Thanks SO much, because when I ask other people they just be rude, but you actually helped. Thanks again to everyone. Night

Comment: I understand, I used to be in your shoes as well. The more you learn the easier it is to ask a well written question. This one wasn't bad, you explained what was wrong and showed the markup you were using which is what allot of us want to see.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is that in your JavaScript you have two "slide" functions while one should be named "slide2" like in your HTML. This will probally still not work due to naming conflict as mentioned in the comments.

Peronal advice, create a class or a object. Currently you are writing the same thing multiple times. Creating an object of this is called Object-Oriented Programming. If you would like to read more about this, here's a good introduction to it:
[Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: YOU SIR ARE A GENIUS. I changed function slide(x) on the second one to:
function slide2(x) and VOILA IT WORKED. Damn I feel so happy. Thanks to Cory and EasyBB.

Peace out.

(I'd vote you up but I need 15 reps)